# How to get values from string by matching keys?

Tags: c#, string

Here is real data in string

```
25459178 for: MARIA PETRUZZELLA on:  2014-05-27
```

I am considering it as

```
[TransactionNumber] for: [Customer] on:  [Date]
```

How do I get the following values

```
TransactionNumber = 25459178 
Customer = MARIA PETRUZZELLA
Date = 2014-05-27
```

Comment: Look at regular expressions.

Comment: I have studied but I am not expert with RE.

Comment: Have added an example for you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

using `String.Split`

```
var input = "25459178 for: MARIA PETRUZZELLA on: 2014-05-27";
var values = input.Split(new[] { "for:", "on:" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var TransactionNumber = values[0];
var Customer = values[1];
var Date = values[2];
```

Note: You can use `Trim` on each value to remove leading and trailing white-spaces.

Comment: Great suggestion. It's nice, clean, and to the point. Often the first reaction may be to use substrings since you can get the index of all the spaces, and know the order of variables, but this skips all that  difficult logic and trouble that indexing may cause.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could work but you would have to ensure that you cover all bases in terms of customer names and that the formatting of the data isn't going to change:

```
string input = "25459178 for: MARIA PETRUZZELLA on:  2014-05-27";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(input, @"(?<Transaction>[0-9]+)\s+for:\s+(?<Customer>[a-zA-Z\- ]+)\s+on:\s+(?<Date>[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})");
string transaction = match.Groups["Transaction"].Value;
string customer = match.Groups["Customer"].Value;
string date = match.Groups["Date"].Value;
DateTime dateObject;
DateTime.TryParse(date, out dateObject);
```

In your case, I'd probably go with Selman22's answer for the sake of simplicity.